# Match a String with optional number of hyphens - Java Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to match Strings with optional number of hyphens.
For example,
string1-string2,
string1-string2-string3,
string1-string2-string3 and so on.

Right now, I have something which matches one hyphen. How can I make the regex to match optional number of hyphens?

My current regex is: arn:aws:iam::\d{12}:[a-zA-Z]*/?[a-zA-Z]*-?[a-zA-Z]*

What do I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^\\w+(-\\w+)*$
```

Explanation:

```
\\w+     - match any string containing [a-zA-Z_0-9]
(-\\w+)* - match a hyphen followed by a string zero or more times
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/cB4fR7/3)

Note that this won't match an empty string, or a string containing weird characters.  You could handle these cases manually or you could update the regex.

Comment: Perfect this worked. I had a follow up question. I would want the maximum number of characters to be 64. I used your expression and added curly braces this way - (\w+(-\w+)*){1,64} It does not seem to work for the length. Is it because of the asterisk that it can have any number of characters ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I would require the total length of the string to be 64. In this case you're limiting each string to 64 characters.

Comment: If you want to limit the length of the string, I would leverage Java's string functions.  In particular, just check the length of the string using `String.length()` and make sure that it has at least one character and no more than 64 characters.  Regular expressions are not suitable for all types of problems.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again !

Comment: There likely is a single regex which would do everything, but it might be very ugly, would be hard to maintain, and wouldn't run as fast as just checking the length.  I am glad I could help.